# hide Google Authentication Qrcode after configured in google authenticater app for next login

Tags: php, authentication, google-authentication, google-authenticator

I have implemented Multi factor Authentication(MFA) with Google Authenticater taking code from **https://www.9lessons.info/2016/06/google-two-factor-authentication-login.html#comment-form**.

- First time when i login with username and password, in the 2nd step QRcode is displayed and once scans QR code from google authenticater user can login successfully
- Below is the code to display QRcode

---

```
<?php
$userClass = new userClass();
$userDetails=(object) $userClass->userDetails($_SESSION['staff_id_temp']);
$secret=$userDetails->google_auth_code;
$ga = new GoogleAuthenticator();
$qrCodeUrl = $ga->getQRCodeGoogleUrl($email, $secret,'Test');
?>          
<div class="form-group">

        <div id='device' style="float:left;margin-left: 200px">
<font color="red"><?php echo $error_msg ?></font><br />
<p>Enter the verification code generated by Google Authenticator app on your phone.</p><br/>
<div id="img">
<img src='<?php echo $qrCodeUrl; ?>' />
</div>
<br/>
<form method="post">
<label>Enter Google Authenticator Code</label>
<input type="text" name="googleauth_code" />
<input type="submit" class="button"/>
</form>
</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

- Issue is when i logged in second time, its asking again the QRcode which it shouldnt be since i already configured in my google authenticater app. How can i hide QRcode on next login, because its making other users to login